# How to run SIP phones in the LAN (NAT Overloaded to single IP)?

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-ios, sip

We have a small office network switch connected to a DSL modem for internet and telephony access. Now we would to extend network to another location in the same building for which I deployed a cisco 1841 router.

Previous Topology:

```
Internet --- DSL Modem --- Office LAN Switch (L2) (192.168.1.0/24) --- SIP Phone
```

New Topology:

```
Internet --- DSL Modem --- Office LAN Switch (L2) (192.168.1.0/24) --- cisco 1841 --- Branch Lan Switch (L2)(192.168.0.0/24) --- SIP Phone
```

SIP phones are connected to cloud PBX at the service provider and the in the previous configuration they were working perfectly.

Now in the second configuration; although we have internet access at the branch; I am having trouble with the SIP phones!!

In this router I have configured a NAT overloading. Can you please tell me what I shall do for SIP phones to work??

Below you can find the configuration and IP NAT SIP debug for cisco 1841.

```
version 12.4
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
resource policy
!
clock timezone GMT 3
ip cef
!
!
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
!
ip dhcp pool MAIN-POOL
   network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
   domain-name mycomp.local
   default-router 192.168.0.1 
   dns-server 192.168.0.1 
!
!
ip domain name mycomp.com
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source list 50 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
!
access-list 50 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
control-plane
!
!
```

debug ip nat sip:

```
Nov  6 07:02:35.678: NAT: SIP: [0] processing unrecognized message
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] processing INVITE message
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: Contact header found
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: Trying to find expires parameter
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:0
Nov  6 07:02:45.385: NAT: SIP: [0] message body found
Nov  6 07:02:45.389: NAT: SIP: Media Lines present:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.389: NAT: SIP: old_sdp_len:306 new_sdp_len :327
Nov  6 07:02:45.421: NAT: SIP: [1] processing SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized message
Nov  6 07:02:45.421: NAT: SIP: [1] translated embedded address 192.168.1.51->192.168.0.14
Nov  6 07:02:45.421: NAT: SIP: [1] translate embedded port 1029->5062
Nov  6 07:02:45.421: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.421: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:0
Nov  6 07:02:45.433: NAT: SIP: [0] processing ACK message
Nov  6 07:02:45.433: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.433: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.433: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] processing INVITE message
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: Contact header found
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: Trying to find expires parameter
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:0
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: [0] message body found
Nov  6 07:02:45.525: NAT: SIP: Media Lines present:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.529: NAT: SIP: old_sdp_len:306 new_sdp_len :327
Nov  6 07:02:45.557: NAT: SIP: [1] processing SIP/2.0 100 Trying message
Nov  6 07:02:45.557: NAT: SIP: [1] translated embedded address 192.168.1.51->192.168.0.14
Nov  6 07:02:45.557: NAT: SIP: [1] translate embedded port 1029->5062
Nov  6 07:02:45.557: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.557: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:0
Nov  6 07:02:45.801: NAT: SIP: [1] processing SIP/2.0 403 Remote is disconnected (last code: 400) message
Nov  6 07:02:45.801: NAT: SIP: [1] translated embedded address 192.168.1.51->192.168.0.14
Nov  6 07:02:45.805: NAT: SIP: [1] translate embedded port 1029->5062
Nov  6 07:02:45.805: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:45.805: NAT: SIP: [1] register:0 door_created:0
Nov  6 07:02:45.813: NAT: SIP: [0] processing ACK message
Nov  6 07:02:45.813: NAT: SIP: [0] translated embedded address 192.168.0.14->192.168.1.51
Nov  6 07:02:45.813: NAT: SIP: [0] translate embedded port 5062->1029
Nov  6 07:02:45.813: NAT: SIP: [0] register:0 door_created:1
Nov  6 07:02:47.677: NAT: SIP: [0] processing unrecognized message
Nov  6 07:02:56.616: NAT: SIP: [0] processing unrecognized message
Nov  6 07:03:05.680: NAT: SIP: [0] processing unrecognized message
Nov  6 07:03:06.431: NAT: SIP: [0] processing unrecognized message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

It seems, `SIP ALG` is `ON` by default and when I disabled `SIP ALG`, `VoIP` clients started working properly:

```
enable
configure terminal
no ip nat service sip udp port 5060
no ip nat service sip tcp port 5060
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.